# Problems getting JSON on Docker deployment with AWS EC2 Golang GO endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, go, amazon-ec2

I am having a hard time on GET request to endpoint of /biz on AWS with Docker file. I made the following project based on this course and would love to hear your insights.

I ran through all the following commands in terminal

```js
docker build -t projectname
docker tag projectname username/projectname
docker push username/projectname
ssh -i ~/.ssh/projectAWS.pem ec2-user@[public-DNS
```

Inside terminal of AWS EC2

```js
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y dockersudo service docker start
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
docker run -d -p 80:80 usernam/projectname
```

When I hit my IPv4 Public IP http://xxx.xxx.xxx/biz, nothing return but "This site can’t be reached"It works on localhost:80/biz when docker run locally. Do you think there's something I am missing? Like the Dockerfile? Missing imports? AWS set-up? Endpoints? or main.go itself? Thanks in advance!

```js
# Dockerfile from Docker
# Start from a Debian image with the latest version of Go installed
# and a workspace (GOPATH) configured at /go.
FROM golang

# Copy the local package files to the container's workspace.
ADD . /go/src/github.com/seintun/dinesty.ninja-backend
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/seintun/dinesty.ninja-backend

# Build the outyet command inside the container.
RUN go get ./
RUN go build

# Run the outyet command by default when the container starts.
ENTRYPOINT /go/bin/dinesty.ninja-backend

# Document that the service listens on port 8080.
EXPOSE 8080
```

```js
package main

import (
  "log"
  "net/http"
  "os"

  "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
  "github.com/gorilla/mux"
  ctrl "github.com/username/projectname/controllers"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.HandleFunc("/biz", ctrl.FetchBiz).Methods("GET")
rLog := handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, r)
 if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", rLog); err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }
}
```

// In case you wonder what ctrl.FetchBiz do, it just GET JSON from mongoDB
package ctrl

```go
import (
  "encoding/json"
  "io/ioutil"
  "log"
  "net/http"

  . "github.com/username/projectname/models"
  "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"

  mgo "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
)

// FetchBiz return list of bizs
func (b *BizDAO) FetchBiz() ([]Biz, error) {
    query := bson.M{"active": true}
    var bizs []Biz
    err := db.C(BCOLLECTION).Find(query).All(&bizs)
    return bizs, err
}
```

Comment: not sure why it works locally, your go app is on 8080. I see no port mapping 8080 to 80 so how did you access it on port 80?

Comment: security group is what I would check next

Answer (score 0):

Your webserver serves to port 8080 `if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", rLog); err != nil {` while you expose and access port 80 `docker run -d -p 80:80 usernam/projectname`

When you use `docker run -d -p 80:8080 usernam/projectname` instead, your webservice should be accessible on port 80 of your host.